# link each active block to it's page url

Tags: blocks, caching

I want to link availaible block bids with active url. Then i want to clear page cache by block. How to do that best way? I wanted to use

```
block_list($region)
```

But it's overhead.

Comment: Sorry for my english.

Comment: Please, add more details about what are you tring to do.

Comment: I think it's important to track block changes and clear page(only pages where block is visible) cache too when block cache was cleared. It's somethink like cache aggregation model. All that stuff i need for my block module with dynamic data.

Comment: Have you tried http://drupal.org/project/cache_actions module?

Comment: Unfortunately using this module I can't clear page cache by expiered block content. My current decision is to create many2many 'block(bid)<->page(url)' table. And clear all page cache where block was used. Maybe theree are more proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing where any block is displayed can be tricky; you would need to keep a nontrivial database table in order to do that (Boost 6.x does this with nodes that are in panels and views). A better option would be to output the block via AJAX or ESI.

http://drupal.org/project/esi/ (has ajax output option)
http://drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks/
http://drupal.org/project/ajaxify_regions/